# Ways to arrange students in a class

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was wondering what the total number of possible seating arrangements in a classroom is.

- There are $10$ students.
- There are $6$ benches, and each can seat $2$ students.
- $8$ students are paired in $4$ benches.
- Rest $2$ students sit alone on $2$ benches.

Is the total number of possible arrangements simply $^{12}P_{10}$ or do more restrictions need to be applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not quite that simple.  We must decide which seats are occupied, then fill them.

There are $\binom{6}{4}$ to select the four benches which will each receive two students.  For the other two benches, there are two ways to select which of the two seats will be occupied, which can be done in $\binom{2}{1}^2$ ways.  Now that we have decided which seats will be occupied, there are $10!$ ways to assign the students to the $10$ seats that will be filled.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{6}{4}\binom{2}{1}^210!$$
possible seating arrangements.